# How do I sum the nth number from the right in all cells

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am using a spreadsheet to collect all my questions and answers for a quiz I am doing. In the answers column, every answer is ended with [#p], # representing the numbers 1–9, never exceeding 9. Example:

Cell D4:

> Each of two or more words having the same spelling or pronunciation
> but different meanings and origins. For example, pole and pole. **[2p]**

Cell D5:

> From the Greek  ὁμός (homós, ‘same’) plus  ὄνυμα (ónyma, ‘name’). **[3p]**

I would like to sum the total amount of points available in each category in D2. (That is: in B2, D2, F2 &c.) I have tried some combinations of `left` and `right`, but can’t get it to collect the number for more than one cell. For example, the function `=LEFT(RIGHT(D4;3);1)` is able to get the character ‘2’, and adding `VALUE` to the front of it – i.e. `=VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(D4;3);1))` – turns the character ‘2’ into the number ‘2’. What I cannot get to work, however, is to add any form of sum function to it, and include the range D4:D. In the image below, I would like D2 to display 5. How can I achieve this?

[image: An image of the quiz sheet]

Comment: Are the categories the letters inside the braces??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in **A1** through **A3** like:

[image]

Pick a cell end enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(RIGHT(A1:A3,3),1))
```

to yield 13.  The `SUMPRODUCT()` function creates an array of the numerals and sums that array.

*(you may require **;** rather than **,**)*

**EDIT#1:**

The double minus sign converts number-as-text into a true number that can be summed.

Comment: That sounds like it could work! What do the double hyphens mean, by the way?

Comment: Edit: It works like a charm. Thank you so much! I understand every aspect of it, except the double hyphens, as noted above.

Comment: @CannedMan  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 2):

What about just having a separate column for the potential number of points?  So question in one column, potential answer in another and potential points in a third which is easier to add up?  Don't complicate things if you don't need to.  ;0)

Comment: While I don’t disagree with your point – indeed, why make it more difficult than necessary? – during my design of the sheet, I ended up with this, and as it happens to be, it makes it easier for me to see how the points are scored for a question when there are multiple points to score in a single question. Example: ‘Gary Gygax (1p) and Dave Arneson (2p). [3p]’